# Error Handler converted exception to fatal

Tags: java, json, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception

The message is converted correctly but still gives an error

The RabbitMQ configuration look like this:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RabbitConfig implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {
    private final RabbitConfigProperties properties;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    public static final String ASSISTANT_STATEMENT_EXCHANGE = "assistant.statement";
    public static final String STATEMENTS_LOAD_REQUEST_QUEUE = "statements.load.request";
    public static final String LOAD_REQUEST_KEY = "load.request";


    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new CachingConnectionFactory(properties.getHostname());

        connectionFactory.setUsername(properties.getUsername());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(properties.getPassword());

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(mapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        messageHandlerMethodFactory.setMessageConverter(consumerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return messageHandlerMethodFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange statementExchange() {
        return ExchangeBuilder.directExchange(ASSISTANT_STATEMENT_EXCHANGE).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue statementLoadRequestQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(STATEMENTS_LOAD_RESPONSE_QUEUE).build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Binding statementLoadRequestBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(statementLoadRequestQueue())
                .to(statementExchange())
                .with(LOAD_REQUEST_KEY);
    }
```

I also have a message sender:

```
@Log4j2
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StatementEmitter {
    private final AmqpTemplate template;
    private final DirectExchange statementExchange;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public void requestStatement(TeacherIdDto dto) {
        try {
            final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(dto);
            Message message = MessageBuilder
                    .withBody(json.getBytes())
                    .setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON)
                    .setContentEncoding("UTF-8")
                    .setDeliveryModeIfAbsentOrDefault(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT)
                    .build();
            template.convertAndSend(statementExchange.getName(), "load.request", message);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Object mapper error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

And consumer:

```
@Log4j2
@Component
@EnableRabbit
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StatementListener {

    @RabbitListener(queues = RabbitConfig.STATEMENTS_LOAD_REQUEST_QUEUE)
    public void processLoadRequest(@NotNull Message<TeacherIdDto> dto) {
        log.info(String.format("Message: %s", dto));
    }
}
```

Dto:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TeacherIdDto implements Serializable {
    private String teacherId;
}
```

If I am sending json through the sender, and my consumer processes it,  I will get this error:

```
2022-11-15 02:37:00.581  INFO 12500 --- [ntContainer#1-1] r.c.t.rabbit.listener.StatementListener  : Message: GenericMessage [payload={teacherId=vbbvnbvnbnvbvn}, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=load.request, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, amqp_receivedExchange=assistant.statement, amqp_deliveryTag=2, amqp_consumerQueue=statements.load.request, amqp_redelivered=false, id=93b00729-f3e6-92fe-c221-d686d00f8982, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-HAq0NGeKCWigy9HyuNKkAA, amqp_lastInBatch=false, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1668469020581}]
2022-11-15 02:37:00.581  WARN 12500 --- [ntContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to convert message
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:156) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1670) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1589) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1577) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1568) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1512) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:993) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:940) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:84) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1317) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1223) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:350) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:309) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:292) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:342) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:366) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:132) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:243) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:146) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (String)"{"teacherId":"vbbvnbvnbnvbvn"}"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1420) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.extractScalarFromObject(DeserializationContext.java:932) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:62) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertBytesToObject(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:411) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertContent(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:378) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:347) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2022-11-15 02:37:00.582  WARN 12500 --- [ntContainer#0-1] ingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy : Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'{"teacherId":"vbbvnbvnbnvbvn"}' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=assistant.statement, receivedRoutingKey=load.request, deliveryTag=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-EoV7E816ZRxiKD0a-L-iYg, consumerQueue=statements.load.response])
2022-11-15 02:37:00.582 ERROR 12500 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:146) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1474) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1758) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1533) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:993) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:940) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:84) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1317) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1223) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to convert message
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:156) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1670) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1589) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1577) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1568) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1512) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:350) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:309) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:292) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:342) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:366) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:132) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:243) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:146) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (String)"{"teacherId":"vbbvnbvnbnvbvn"}"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1420) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.extractScalarFromObject(DeserializationContext.java:932) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:62) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertBytesToObject(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:411) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertContent(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:378) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:347) ~[spring-amqp-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

But if I send the same message via the RabbitMQ interface, the error does not occur

```
2022-11-15 02:41:08.265  INFO 12500 --- [ntContainer#1-1] r.c.t.rabbit.listener.StatementListener  : Message: GenericMessage [payload={teacherId=vbbvnbvnbnvbvn}, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=load.request, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, amqp_receivedExchange=assistant.statement, amqp_deliveryTag=4, amqp_consumerQueue=statements.load.request, amqp_redelivered=false, id=bd0ca679-bb20-4344-94e8-c3ac2dcd2712, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-HAq0NGeKCWigy9HyuNKkAA, amqp_lastInBatch=false, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1668469268265}]
```

The body and header of the message are the same, but why does the error occur and in what place? Because the program first outputs data, and then gives an error.

Also, I had the following situation.
I force an exception during message processing. The message is returned to the queue after which it is processed without errors

Comment: If it works from the console and not from code you are obviously **not** sending the same message. I don't get why you are sending a `Message` and still do a convert. It will now try to convert `Message` to JSON, whereas you probably expect it to only send the body and the rest as headers. You must call `send` instead of `convertAndSend`.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I just started to understand the functionality of amqp and watched tutorials. There, when working with a message, the author also uses convertAndSend instead of send

Comment: I doubt he did. I suspect he received a message and send an object.

Comment: 4 code block from the end of the [article](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/02/springboot-messaging-rabbitmq.html)

Comment: That tutorial is just wrong. Probably a sloppy/paste error.